# Selective versioning with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my app I need object modification history. This approach fits it quite nicely:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_history

However, since the data entered is quite complex, I do not want it saved every time with a new version; it's only after data validation, editing, etc. that the object should be committed and versioned upon modification from that moment on.

Of course I can create a `MyClassScratchpad` for every `MyClass`, get users fill `MyClassScratchpad` instance and then copy to `MyClass` instance for versioning but that's rather cumbersome.

Can versioning be suspended on an SQA object and then turned on later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revisited the issue since it's the same row that gets versioned with changing numbers when using `versioned_history`, and I needed an audit trail with multiple rows to have the history of changed values. `versioned_rows.py` does that:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_rows

The necessary modification turned out to be trivial:

```
class VersionExtension(SessionExtension):
    def before_flush(self, session, flush_context, instances):
        for instance in session.dirty:
            ...
            if hasattr(instance, '_suspend_versioning') and getattr(instance, '_suspend_versioning') is True:
                continue
```